# How to control the CSS and Javascript bundle caching value?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2013, bundle, bundles

When using a bundle in Visual Studio 2013, it is being cached as follows:

```
<link href="/bundles/sampleCss?v=fWN2j-N0EDP-5nxnBDxsSC0LGpCTgC5uV4sGoppoO-g1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How can I set a different value to the name? maybe something more descriptive - like time stamp?
I wonder if I can override something that sets that name...?

Answer (score 0):

looks like someone has created a a Bundling Extension package

https://github.com/unger/Bundling.Extensions

It should help you figure out what needs to be done, or you could just use it.